Using matplotlib pcolormesh, how can I stop the drawn tiles from one row to be connected to the rows above and below?
I have individual x arrays for each intensity (Z) array. Which means that the intensity rows will not be stacked on top of each other. I do not want the tiles to "tilt" so they are connected to the row above and below, I just want them to be straight in the y direction and connected in the x direction. Thank you very much in advance!
Here is a dummy code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_values = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=float)

x_list = range(50, 70)

x_values_list = []
z_values_list = []
for i in range(len(y_values)):
    x_value_single_list = [np.array(0.01*x**2 + 0.1*x*i + 0.3 * i, dtype= float) for x in x_list]
    x_values_list.append( x_value_single_list)
    z_values_list.append(np.random.rand(20))

z_values_list = [np.array(arr, dtype=float) for arr in z_values_list]
x_values_list = [np.array(arr, dtype=float) for arr in x_values_list]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

c = ax.pcolormesh(x_values_list, y_values, z_values_list, cmap='viridis') #, shading='auto'
plt.colorbar(c)
plt.show()


I have tried a bunch of kwargs but a lot of them does not seem to do anything and seem to not be implemented for pcolormesh and more suited for regular line plots. I have obviously tried a lot with ChatGPT.

If you use flat shading, where x and y represent the corners of each quadrilateral, then you can plot one row at a time.  Note I explicitly set the vmin and vmax parameter in the pcolormesh call so that the colour range will be the same for each row even if their actual max and min differ.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y_values = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=float)
x_list = range(50, 70)

for i in range(len(y_values) - 1):
    x_value_single_list = [np.array(0.01*x**2 + 0.1*x*i + 0.3 * i, dtype= float) for x in x_list]
    z_values = np.random.rand(1, 19)  # 2D array but single row.
    
    c = ax.pcolormesh(x_value_single_list, y_values[i:i+2], z_values, cmap='viridis',
                      shading='flat', vmin=0, vmax=1)

plt.colorbar(c)
plt.show()



Omg I can't believe I got this solved so fast. I love you RuthC!!
